# Test for homogenity of variances, Levene's test and fligner-kileen yield different results

Tags: variance, descriptive-statistics, levenes-test

I have two sets of data, in which the first dataset contains 3346 values and the second dataset contains 1168 values. The variance of the first one is 13.88% and variance of the second one 13.96%

The data in both sets is not normally distributed, hence using the $F$-test here is not recommended according the literature. I've looked for other methods and found the Flinger-Kileen and the Levene's test.

So I did a quick calculation in R and Levene's test results in a `Pr(>F)` value of `0.09973` (center=median), which indicates non-significance and the presence of homogenity of variances. On the other hand, the Fligner test results in a p value of `3.14*10^-7`, which is near zero.  So according to the Fligner test, I don't have homogeneity of variance in both datasets.

Which one can I trust? 
I uploaded both datasets on pastebin, if you are interested.
https://pastebin.com/fPNNbL1G

Thank you very much